# HAProxy http-request with DATAPLANE API

Tags: httprequest, haproxy, api-gateway

I am fiddling around with dataplaneapi which is a great addition.
However, I cant find proper parameters for manipulating a http-request in my frontend. The rule needs to look like this:

```
http-request replace-header Host .* 1595708099.pages.domain.de if ACL_somename_de
```

My current request goes to http_request_rules endpoint: /services/haproxy/configuration/http_request_rules
The request body looks like this:

```
{ "cond": "if", "cond_test": "ACL_somename_de", "hdr_name": "Host", "index": 0, "type": "replace-header" }
```

The output is:

```
http-request replace-header Host if ACL_somename_de
```

However I am still missing the regex condition part. On the regular HAproxy docs its called and
See:
https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/aloha/12-5/traffic-management/lb-layer7/http-rewrite/

I cant find these values in the dataplane documentation.
https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/dataplaneapi/latest/#operation/createHTTPRequestRule

Is this even possible and if yes how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the folks over at github and they delivered the answer:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url 'http://127.0.0.1:5679/v2/services/haproxy/configuration/http_request_rules?parent_name=test_2&parent_type=frontend&version=61' \
  --header 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
  "cond": "if",
  "cond_test": "ACL_somename_de",
  "index": 0,
  "type": "replace-header",
  "hdr_format": "1595708099.pages.domain.de",
  "hdr_match": ".*",
  "hdr_name": "Host"
}'
```

Source: [dataplaneapi github issues](https://github.com/haproxytech/dataplaneapi/issues/149).